# Trouble matching and setting values from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, csv, pandas, gtfs

I am trying to match the `stop_id` in `stop_times.csv` to the `stop_id` in `stops.csv` in order to copy over the `stop_lat` and `stop_lon` to their respective columns in `stop_times.csv`.

Gist files:

`stops.csv` [LINK](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/a051cecd6a8821d54188)

`stop_times.csv` [LINK](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/bbd5feed69b2830ae295)

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

st = pd.read_csv('csv/stop_times.csv', sep=',')
st.set_index(['trip_id','stop_sequence'])
stops = pd.read_csv('csv/stops.csv')

for i in range(len(st)):
    for x in range(len(stops)):
        if st['stop_id'][i] == stops['stop_id'][x]:
            st['stop_lat'][i] = stops['stop_lat'][x]
            st['stop_lon'][i] = stops['stop_lon'][x]

st.to_csv('csv/stop_times.csv', index=False)
```

I'm aware that the script is applying a copy, but I'm not sure what other method to go about doing this, as I'm fairly new to pandas.

Comment: Aside: `set_index` doesn't act in place, so the `st.set_index` line doesn't change `st`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge` the two DataFrames:

```
pd.merge(stops, st, on='stop_id')
```

Since there are `stop_lat` columns in each, it will give you `stop_lat_x` (the good one) and `stop_lat_y` (the always-zero one).  You can then remove or ignore the bad column and output the resulting DataFrame however you want.

Comment: How would you implement the `pd.merge`? I tried just doing `st = pd.merge(stops,st,on='stop_id')` and that messed up my csv pretty badly.

The answer is not very obvious to me, so if you could extrapolate a little further that would be appreciated.

Comment: I would look at the result from `merge` and remove the columns I didn't want.  And I would be more specific than "it messed up badly."  :)

Comment: I see. By messed up, I realized that what it did was change the ordering around. I'll just apply a sort again and get it in the correct order. This answer worked, thanks a bunch! I spent 6 hours trying different methods. :(

Comment: You're welcome.  When you find yourself writing loops in Pandas/NumPy/SciPy, you usually should take a step back and figure out how to do it the "right" way, with vectorized operations.  It's much faster to execute anyway.